# Force dependencies for gradle in cordova config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, phonegap

I'm trying to add exact dependencies, but it looks like all of them ignored in */platforms/android/project.properties* and */platforms/android/build.gradle*

**config.xml**

```
<widget>
    <platform name="android">
        <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.8.0" />
        <framework src="com.google.gms.google-services:9.8.0" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="6.2.3" />
    <engine name="cordova" spec="6.5.0" />
    <engine name="npm" spec="4+" />
</widget>
```

The output is:

**project.properties**

```
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add `<framework>` tags in `config.xml`: they are [supported in `plugin.xml`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#framework) but not [`config.xml`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html).

However, to achieve what you are trying to do (force Play Services version to v9), you can use [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release):

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release#v9
```

That branch contains a [bit of Gradle config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release/blob/v9/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release.gradle) to override the version to v9.